# making y axis labels shorter in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot in R shiny.
That's the data that I am trying to plot while `Variables` os the x-axis, `r_sqrd` is on the y-axis, and `colour` for defining the colour of the bars.

```
> head(table)
                                                             Variables    r_sqrd colour
1   ifelse.glm(5.863 + -0.1 * NAME1 + -0.041 * NAME1 + -1.042 * NAME1) 0.4643450    Pos
2 ifelse.glm(7.472 + -0.041 * Name2 + -1.128 * Name2 + -0.075 * Name2) 0.4573173    Pos
3  ifelse.glm(5.504 + 0.031 * Name3 + -0.035 * Name3 + -0.012 * Name3) 0.4363604    Pos
4                                                 num.of.lettersName4) 0.1888032    Neg
5 ifelse.glm(4.474 + -0.028 * Name5 + -0.371 * Name5 + -0.147 * Name5) 0.1472681    Neg
6                                                                Name6 0.1460835    Neg
```

That's the code that I am using:

```
p <- ggplot(table, aes(x=as.factor(Variables), y=r_sqrd, fill=colour)) +  
  labs(x="Variables",y="Importance (R square)") + geom_bar(stat="identity") +  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = table$Variables[order(table$r_sqrd)]) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Pos"="darkgreen", "Neg"="darkred")) + theme(legend.position="none")
print(p)
```

[image]
My Problem is that the names in y axis labels are too long which make the plot smaller.

so I used the `str_wrap` function:

```
p <- ggplot(table, aes(x=as.factor(Variables), y=r_sqrd, fill=colour)) +  
  labs(x="Variables",y="Importance (R square)") + geom_bar(stat="identity") +  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 25),limits = table$Variables[order(table$r_sqrd)]) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Pos"="darkgreen", "Neg"="darkred")) + theme(legend.position="none")
print(p)
```

but the result that I got is:

[image]
Is there any Way to get this plot in a proper way

Comment: Here in my RStudio session it looks really nice. You can try to add `axis.text.y =  element_text(size=5)` in the `theme()` function to make the labels smaller.

Comment: Hi @Jimbou, I wonder if there is a way to tackle the issue without changing the text size but rather increase the space for each text's column - I guess it should be a kind of a text wrapping like in Ms excel.